# How to make my android emulator work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

hello I started android and I am working with android studio. 
my laptop is a surface pro 4 and when I try to run my emulator it takes forever, I tried to wait for over 10 hours but it didn't work. The emulator runs perfectly and the picture of the phone shows up but it doesn't go to the main page. I have also installed the "HAXM" but I think the problem is that my computer is weak so I wanted to see if you guys have any ideas for me on how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have all emulator updates installed. Try enabling hardware acceleration, and devote more RAM to the emulator. Try using the Intel x86 Atom image. Your computer should be able to run it.

Comment: I am using as much ram as possible and i am using x86 atom image but the main page of the emulator doesn't start

Comment: Make sure you have the necessary API downloaded for the version of Android you're trying to emulate. And "as much ram as possible" may be too much. I believe the emulator on Windows only runs stable with a max of 512MB allocated by default.

Comment: oh i got this new msg if it  helps:

Comment: HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode

Comment: i figured it out thank you very much